# There is no bounded linear surjection between $\ell_p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

For $1\leq p,q<\infty$, $p\ne q$, how to prove that there is no bounded linear operator $T:\ell_p\to \ell_q$  such that $T$ is surjective?

I've tried to use Pitt's theorem, but without success.

Comment: Do you see that the case $p>q$ follows from Pitt's theorem? In the other case,  one can consider the adjoint $T^*$, which would be an isomorphism of   $\ell_{q'}$ onto a subspace of $\ell_{p'}$

Comment: @NormalHuman, yes I've done that, but the problem arise when $p=1$, which implies $\ell_p^*=\ell_\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

By assumption $p\neq q$.

**Case 1:** $p,q\in(1,+\infty)$. Assume we have a surjection $T:\ell_p\to\ell_q$, then $T^*:\ell_{q'}\to \ell_{p'}$ is an embedding. Since $p',q'\in(1,+\infty)$, we get a contradiction because by corollary of Pitt's theorem theses spaces are totally incomparable. Thus for this case a desired surjection doesn't exists.

**Case 2:** $q=1, p\in(1,+\infty)$. Similarly, we have an embedding $T^*:\ell_\infty\to\ell_{p'}$. Since $p'\in(1,+\infty)$, then $\ell_{p'}$ is separable, but $\ell_\infty$ is not. So $T^*$ can't be an embedding. For this case we don't have a surjection either.

**Case 3:** $p=1, q\in(1,+\infty)$. Since $q\in(1,+\infty)$, then $\ell_q$ is separble. It is remains to recall that any separable Banach space is quotient of $\ell_1$. So this is the only case when a surjection does exists.

Comment: Norbert, I didn't understand the second case. So we first see that $T^*$ is injective with $Dom(T^*)=l_\infty$. But then how do we conclude that since $\overline{T^*(l_\infty)}$ is separable, that $l_\infty$ should also be (which is the contradiction). Though, I have another solution for Case 2: $l_p$ is reflexive and $l_1$ is the image of the bounded linear map $T$. So $l_1$ has to be also reflexive which is a contradiction (see Corollary 1.11.22 in Megginson's book *An introduction to Banach spaces* )

Comment: @Svetoslav , since $T^*$ is an embedding, then $\ell_\infty\cong \operatorname{Im}(T^*)\subset\ell_{p'}$. Thus we have a non-separable subspace (that is $\operatorname{Im}(T^*)$) inside a separable space $\ell_{p'}$. Contradiction.

Comment: But why $l_\infty$ is isomorphic to $Im(T^*)$ as $Im(T^*)$ may not be closed ?

Comment: It IS closed. There is a theorem that a adjoint of surjective operator between Banach spaces is closed.

Comment: Yes, the adjoint operator is always a closed operator, but this does not mean that the range of the adjoint is closed.... Ahaa, I see, because  $T$ is onto, so its range is closed and so the range of the adjoint is also closed. Now it is clear.